# What is the benefit of Fast track services?

Tags: sharepoint-online, migration, fasttrack

According to [Fasttrack faqs](https://www.microsoft.com/en-in/fasttrack/faqs?rtc=1) I understand what Fasttrack program can help in migrating data to online. But I am having few doubts with this?

1. If Microsoft is involving in between me and customer and helping to migrate data for free of cost, then why customer will choose my services? Customer can directly contact Microsoft and ask for help if they are having min requirement of licenses.
2. During FastTrack program Microsoft just give suggestions or do they provide Information Architecture changes also? Means if I want to move my on-premises SP to online which is having large lists, do Fasttrack program provide better way of planning IA and migration?
3. What are the things that FastTrack program cannot provide?

Comment: This question is too broad, the answers are very likely to include some level of opinions and this is only barely concerning SharePoint and SharePoint.SE's scope. Only a very seasoned FastTrack AND several MS technology understanding person may provide somewhat sufficient answers to these matters, so you would anyway get reasonably better answers from Microsoft's support directly. Anyway, as FastTrack is for the ones with M365/Azure/D365 subscription, the support should be accessible equally.